Retrieve server variable with vite vuejs in a docker
I have the same docker image with my vuejs (with vite) deployed in 3 different environment (stage, qa and prod) with kubernetes, in this 3 environment i have the same environment variable with 3 differents values, for exemple: in stage i have VITE_APP_URL=test1, in qa i have VITE_APP_URL=test2 and in prod i have VITE_APP_URL=test3. In my code i have this lines to retrieve the value: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_URL but when i go check the variable it return nothing.. I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve the environment variable on my front which is on the server.
This is my Dockerfile if it can help:
FROM node:20.10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# étape de production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


The docs say "Vite exposes env variables on the special import.meta.env object, which are statically replaced at build time". So they get the values they have at build time. You can't set them at run-time.

Option 1
The environment variable is hard coded into the Dockerfile. This does not seem ideal. See Option 2 below.
FROM node:20.10 as build-stage

ENV VITE_APP_URL=test2

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Option 2
Have a collection of environment files, the appropriate one chosen at build time.
For example:
 .env-staging
VITE_APP_URL=test1

 .env-qa
VITE_APP_URL=test2

 .env-prod
VITE_APP_URL=test3

Modify Dockerfile as follows:
FROM node:20.10 as build-stage

ARG ENV_FILE
ENV ENV_FILE=${ENV_FILE}

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN cp ${ENV_FILE} .env && \
    npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Now you specify the appropriate environment file as a build argument, using whichever of the following is appropriate.
docker build --build-arg ENV_FILE=.env-staging -t vite-app .
docker build --build-arg ENV_FILE=.env-qa -t vite-app .
docker build --build-arg ENV_FILE=.env-prod -t vite-app .


Thanks, i used the option 2 and it works perfectly !
